# How to use REST API data with moment isBetween to update open/closing times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I am trying to pull some data from a REST API and use it with Moment to update the opening/closing time of an online store. Below is a sample of my REST API data

```
"id": 1,
"store_open_close": {
    "enabled": true,
    "time": {
        "sunday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "10:00",
            "closing_time": "21:00"
        },
        "monday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "10:00",
            "closing_time": "21:00"
        },
        "tuesday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "10:00",
            "closing_time": "21:00"
        },
        "wednesday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "10:00",
            "closing_time": "21:00"
        },
        "thursday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "10:00",
            "closing_time": "21:00"
        },
        "friday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "10:00",
            "closing_time": "23:00"
        },
        "saturday": {
            "status": "open",
            "opening_time": "11:00 am",
            "closing_time": "22:00"
        }
    },
    "open_notice": "We are open",
    "close_notice": "Sorry we are closed"
},
"id": 2...
```

Here is the code i am using now that manually sets the open/closing times

```
 isStoreOpen() {
    // Get formatted time
    const current_time = new moment()
    const format = "LT"
    const time = moment(current_time, format),
        beforeTime = moment("10:00", format),
        afterTime = moment("21:00", format);

    // Check if current time is between open and close times
    if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
        this.setState({ restaurantOpen: true })
    } else {
        this.setState({ restaurantOpen: false })
    }
},
```

...
I need something like

```
if (restaruantstores.id === product.store.id) { isStoreOpen() { ... } }
```

I am trying to use the data from the REST API as the beforeTime and afterTime. I was able to successfully display the open/closing times (with some help last month from Paul here on StackOverflow).

```
item.store_open_close.time[currentDay.toLowerCase()].opening_time
```

but I am trying to remotely update these times via REST API 
Any help, much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by remotely updating the opening times?

Comment: the data in the rest api above is just a sample, there are dozens of stores and restaurants in the data, all with different opening/closing times. as I have it now, they are all using the same beforeTime and afterTime, I would like to pull the opening_time and closing_time from the rest api data and set it to beforeTime and afterTime so when viewing the stores on the front end, it would display either closed or open depending on the time of day. (sorry for any confusion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the item like

```js
isStoreOpen() {
// ...
const weekdays = [
  '-',
  'monday',
  'tuesday',
  'wednesday',
  'thursday',
  'friday',
  'saturday',
  'sunday',
];
const currentDay = weekdays[moment().isoWeekday()];
const storeHours = store_open_close.time[currentDay];

// now you can use any properties like status, opening_time, closing_time

// here the code of your function continues
// ...
```

Refer to the [isoWeekdays documentation from moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/)

Comment: Thanks, Julian. But how do I load the rest api data in the isStoreOpen() { ... bit? Right now the data is in this.state.restaruantstores

Comment: You can use fetch or axios, see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Thanks, I am already storing the data in something like this.state.restaruantstores

Comment: then instead of writing `const storeHours = store_open_close.time[currentDay];` you would write `const storeHours = this.state. restaruantstores.store_open_close.time[currentDay];`

Comment: Thanks again Julian, this is leading me down the right path. My issue is there are many stores with the above rest api data, so I need to match the store data with an ID so it only shows the open/close times for that store/id. right now it's rendering all the open times and triggering an error. thanks